# missing ; after for-loop initializer

Tags: javascript

```
var nodeWordsString = document.getElementById("nodeWordsTextArea").value.trim();
    var nodeWordsStringArray=nodeWordsString.split(" ");
    var strLength = nodeWordsStringArray.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeWordsStringArray.length; i++)----->******
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < nodeWordsStringArray.length; j++)
        {
            if(nodeWordsStringArray(i) == nodeWordsStringArray(j))
            {
                alert("Node duplication occurred at:"+nodeWordsStringArray(i));
                return false;
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
```

******showing error like `missing ; after for-loop initializer` in java script console(firebug).
please help me.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This is [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), but you're using `int` in your loop declaration? Try replacing those with `var` instead.

Comment: @Raynos: Was going to ask you the same. ;-)

Comment: @vissu pepala: Don't worry about it, everyone's here to help without passing judgement. I know I've had many-a-night coding and did a face-palm the next morning to some stupid error I couldn't see the night before. ;-)

Comment: Just made the same mistake :-) and found the soln straight away thanks to your question

Comment: Same mistake here too. Force of habit is the stronger the deeper the night is.

Comment: @Raynos - years have passed and people are making the same mistakes, lol :D [same here]

Answer (score 14):

In my case, the error was caused by using `let` in the loop. Old browsers like Firefox 38 doesn't support `let`.

Replacing `let` by `var` solved the issue.

Comment: I was having the same problem today in FF38 but the really irritating part is that the code works fine in the dev tools console, but not on my page. 

I tried adding [code]"use strict";[/code] but all that did was create a different error message without a line number.

Answer (score 5):

Change `int i` and `int j` to `var i` and `var j`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are here in 2016, maybe you are trying to use a `let` declaration outside strict mode in a browser that does not yet support it. Replace it with `var` or add `'use strict;'` to the top of your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var strLength = nodeWordsStringArray.length;
for(int i = 0; i < nodeWordsStringArray.length; i++)
```

You can use `for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++)` it is more efficient. As for your actual error try moving your brackets to the end of your for line. `for(..;..;..) {`

P.S. as mentioned there is no `int`.