# How to create a 2D array for react

Tags: reactjs

This is my code thus far for a `getCoordinates` function that produces a list of coordinates in a grid.

```
getCoordinates = () => {
        let result = []
        for (int i = 1; i <= this.state.gridSize; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j <= this.state.gridSize; j++){
                result.push([i*100, j*100])
            }
        }
        return result;
};
```

I want to return something like for gridSize = 4

```
[[100, 100], [100, 200], [100, 300], [100, 400],
[200, 100], [200, 200], [200, 300], [200, 400],
[300, 100], [300, 200], [300, 300], [300, 400],
[400, 100], [400, 200], [400, 300], [400, 400]]
```

Can anyone please help me get the correct syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5718068/3001761? Note that it's helpful to include the actual output as part of your [mcve] (and, prior to even posting, to search for your error messages).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the declaration of the variables `i` and `j`. Currently they're declared with Java (or similar) syntax. Instead those `int` key words should be replaced with `let`.

Like this:

```js
getCoordinates = () => {
    let result = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.state.gridSize; i++){
        for (let j = 1; j <= this.state.gridSize; j++){
            result.push([i*100, j*100])
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```